# How to use scopes to get the last (highest id) in a has_many relationship in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Each `Client` has_many `Order`s.

How to eager load all Clients and the last (highest id) order for each Client?

The following did not work:

```
Client.includes( :orders ).where( 'orders.count > 0' )
```

and

```
Client.includes( :orders ).where( orders: 'count > 0 ' )
```

Answer (score 0):

Think you need a join and not an eager load to query the association like that.

`Client.joins(:orders).where('orders.count > ?', 0)`

Another thing, if your table name is different than your association name then you will need to use the table name for orders where you have 'orders.count' instead of orders but leave the joins(:orders) as is.